How to pull stats from a google cloud tasks queue that has finished?
I'm trying to figure out how to pull the following stats from a Google Cloud tasks queue in the past that has finished executing filtered by date perhaps? I'm running a queue Mon, Wed, Fri every week, and I need to get some useful stats once the queue finish everytime...

Nr of dispatched tasks
Nr of successful dispatched tasks (200 status code)
Nr of unsuccessful dispatched tasks (Meaning all retries failed for a task)
Timestamp queue execution start
Timestamp queue finished

Node.js solution or using google cloud cli is fine.
I can only find this doc:
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/3.0.2/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta2.QueueStats.html
But it's not what I need really..
Alternatively, I guess a solution is to just trigger a webhook event when there are no more tasks in the queue. That could work as well, and I just log the individual requests to a db table, and then once the queue has finished I can pull the data I need from the db. So instructions how to configure the webhook event for when there are no more tasks in a given queue with google cloud platform is also an accepted answer.
